# Looping a mesh pattern inside and outside of a cone shape

Tags: mesh, add-on, 3d-printing

I was trying to create a mesh pattern that loops inside and outside of a cone shape using the  tissue add-on but there maybe another way to do this that I just haven't thought of.

I'm trying to **create a mesh pattern that loops inside and outside of a cone shape similar to the torus below with the red band** that starts and finishes at the same place / face **but using a cone shape.**

[image: Image1]

Animated Loop of mesh being selected that goes all the way around the inside to the outside and back again.

[image: Loop being selected that goes all the way around the inside to the outside and back again]

**Cone shape I'm trying to apply a similar looping mesh to:**

[image: Cone shape]

Is this possible using just Blender 2.91?

I have tried applying the **"Simple Deform modifier"**  using the **Stretch** option to the Torus to see if I could stretch it into the correct cone dimensions (see image below), **but it messes up the top and bottom and it warps the cone shape.**

**This will be 3D printed so I'm trying to get the dimensions to stay within that cone shape.**

[image: Image warp]

PS: I was trying to do this with Tissue 0.3.48 on Ubuntu 20.04
and Blender 2.91.  But willing to try something else / another technique.

For more background / history trying to do this with the Tissue add-on: [Link](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue/issues/89)

[image]

Comment: I think you don't need face loops, but just the the good faces, do you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "good faces" but the highlighted faces just shows one full cycle of the loop, but I do need the other face loops.

Comment: From the deformed torus, use knife tool with Z cut. Then move GG the cut to the upper (and lower) part.